# Issue in storing @Value returned value in another string

Tags: spring-boot

```
  @Value("${Loc}"
    private String downloadLoc;// returning the value
    
     DateTimeFormatter dtf=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
        String date=dtf.format(LocalDate.now());
        String trigFileName="FEED_"+date+".trg";
    String updatedLoc=downloadLoc+ trigFileName;
```

//downloadLoc value returned as null when trying store in updatedLoc

Comment: I have to read value from properties and then make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

we need a properties file to define the values we want to inject with the @Value annotation, for that first we need to define a @PropertySource in our configuration class — with the properties file name

add this to your application.properties file

```
Loc=[any value you want to specify]
```

if you want the value to be dynamic try constructor injection where you just need to declare in properties file but not assign

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class LocProvider {

    private String loc;

    @Autowired
    public LocProvider(@Value("${Loc}") String loc) {
        this.loc= loc;
    }

    // standard getter
```

and create an object in your class like this

```
LocProvider value = new LocProvider("abc");
```

Comment: I have to read the value from properties file and then make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check

1. Make sure you imported right package (`org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation`)
2. Make sure you have an entry in `application.properties` file. For eg: `Loc=SOME VALUE`
3. If you have `application.properties` file at some other location, specify it in start args (`--spring.config.location=<PATH TO THE FILE>`). Refer this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for more details